# Geogebra for Blind People

Tags: geometry, education

I work in the University with students in a situation of disability, specifically, teaching them math and related things. I have a few students that are blind, they work with JAWS or NVDA usually.

When we are working in Calculus or some course which depends a bit in visual things to be understood, it goes slow.

I'd like that the dynamics of the teaching were more fluid. So, I'm searching for some way to teach Geogebra, so they can applicate these things for their purpose of study. Sadly, I think that Geogebra isn't too accesible for this.

I wonder if anyone have some great idea to do a good geometric work with some accesible software or if you know somehow to work with Geogebra for this purpose.

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: Absolutely perfect question for https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @TheoBendit Thank you ! I didn't know about that page :)

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15466/geogebra-for-blind-people). It's a better fit on MESE, so I'm voting to close this as "off-topic".